# Passing no arguments while calling function through dict

Tags: python

I have made a Python script which calls functions based on user's input. Until now I was calling argument-less functions simply through a dict

```
options = { 0 : func0,
            1 : func1,
            2 : func2,
           }
options[choice]()
```

Now I am in a situation where I need to call a few functions with arguments. I am new to Python and I tried something like this

```
options = { 0 : (func0,None),
            1 : (func1,None),
            2 : (func2,foo1),
            3 : (func3,foo2),
          }
options[choice][0](options[choice][1])
```

I am aware why `None` doesn't work here, and have written it just to symbolize that the function doesn't take any arguments. What changes should I make in the code so that it works for all kinds of functions?

I tried unpacking `empty dict` but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`None` is still a value, and passing it to a function that is not expecting arguments will not work. Instead consider using [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) here

```
from functools import partial

options = { 0: func0,
            1: func1,
            2: partial(func2, foo1),
            3: partial(func3, foo2),
          }

options[choice]()
```

Answer (score 18):

Use a lists of arguments:

```
options = { 0 : (func0, []),
            1 : (func1, []),
            2 : (func2, [foo1]),
            3 : (func3, [foo2]),
          }
options[choice][0](*options[choice][1])
# or
func, args = options[choice]
func(*args)
```

If you want to be able to specify named arguments as well, you can extend it like this:

```
options = { 0 : (func0, [], {}),
            1 : (func1, [], {param_name: value}),
            2 : (print_name, [], {name: "nims"}),
            3 : (func3, [foo2], {}),
          }
func, args, kwargs = options[choice]
func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: OP could also consider having **kwargs as well, stored as a dict after *args

Comment: @jamylak: Good idea, I'll add that to my post.

Comment: @jamylak: Oh, thanks for the edit, now that was an unpack fail :)

Comment: @nims: Note that you can do that in gnibbler's solution very naturally: `partial(func, foo1, p_name=foo2)`

Answer (score 4):

You could use lambda expressions for the functions with arguments (and leave the ones without as you have them now):

```
options = { 0 : func0,
            1 : func1,
            2 : lambda: func2(foo1),
            3 : lambda: func3(foo2),
          }
```

Comment: I much prefer the `partial` solution, it's the best way to do this approach.

Comment: Agreed, it also allows to pass additional parameters elegantly.

Comment: What is the great advantage in this case?

Comment: In gnibbler's solution, you could add parameters to `options[choice]()`, which will be passed to the original function. You would have to extend your `lambda`s like this: `lambda *args, **kwargs: func2(foo1, *args, **kwargs)` which isn't very elegant IMHO.

Comment: @MichaelMauderer Also `partial` will most likely be faster.

Comment: @phant0m wait he won't have to do all that. Anyway the main thing is that `partial` was built to do this and is optimized for it so may as well use it.

Comment: @jamylak To get this working: `options[choice](shared_name=shared_param)`, yes, he would have to do all that. But whether that is ever needed in practice is a different question. In the case of gnibbler's code, there won't be any modifications necessary to allow for that.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this :

use `*` in function header, it'll collect all the arguments in a tuple.

```
def func0(*a):
    print list(a)
def func1(*a):
    print list(a)
def func2(*a):
    print list(a)
def func3(*a):
    print list(a)
foo1=1
foo2=2
options = { 0 : (func0,None),
            1 : (func1,None),
            2 : (func2,foo1),
            3 : (func3,foo2),
          }
choice=2
options[choice][0](options[choice][1:])  #prints [(1,)]

choice=1
options[choice][0](options[choice][1:])  #prints [(None,)]
```